# Django and Heroku - Migration is applied before its dependency

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm having trouble getting my Django web app from a local server to Heroku. To try and troubleshoot I created a new app from scratch and managed to push that through to Heroku with no problems.

The issue comes when I add

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

to models.py, then run makemigrations and migrate.

The error is:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:
> Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency
> mainapp.0001_initial on database 'default'.

One thing that might be causing it is that I'm using sqlite3 on localhost then Postgres on the Heroku server (although I'm not advanced enough to know if that is actually the problem!)

Also my gitignore file contains:

```
/venv
__pycache__
db.sqlite3
mainapp/static/
```

Should it also include the migrations folder?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Full traceback is:

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
remote:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
remote:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
remote:     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 95, in handle
remote:     executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 306, in check_consistent_history
remote:     connection.alias,
remote: django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency mainapp.0001_initial on database 'default'.
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
```

**Edit**

mainapp.0001_initial.py:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.5 on 2021-01-23 12:04

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**SOLUTION**
Figured it out - I needed to have created the user model before running migrations (and before pushing to Heroku, as that runs migrations too). I made another clean install, set up django, created user model THEN pushed to Heroku.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Comment: Add mainapp.0001_initial.py & admin.0001_initial.py code.

Comment: I added mainapp.0001_initial.py but I'm unsure where to find the other one

Comment: The error is caused by the tables with `ForeignKey` to `User` are already being migrated. You would need to delete all migrations, and reset your db (manually by dropping), and migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, unfortunately I had to delete all data locally and in heroku:

Locally: Delete the migration files from the `AbstractUser` app, delete all tables related to it as well locally or, easier in my opinion, delete the local database and recreate a new one, makemigrations again and migrate specifying the `AbstractUser` app specificaly, like:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations abstract_user_app
$ python manage.py migrate abstract_user_app
```

Before deploying to Heroku, go to your application profile in the UI, then resources, click in your database and in settings reset the database (I think with the basic database add-on you can't do it from the command line).

Finally deploy to heroku:

```
$ push heroku main -f
```

and migrate manually from heroku:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate abstract_user_app
```

Refresh the browser and enjoy!